# set iframe height same as one of the div id in its source

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a file as index_scorm.html. Few lines of code is as below :

```
<div class="cpMainContainer" id="cpDocument" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; height: 627px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"> 
    <div id="main_container" style="top: 0px; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 627px; left: 0px;">
       <div id="projectBorder" style="top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;position:absolute;display:block">
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am calling this index_scorm.html file as a iframe inside index.html file. I want to have the height of this iframe same as the height of div with id="cpDocument". I cant simply set the iframe height using height attribute as 627px; because height of "cpDocument" keeps on changing with different screen sizes. i want to achieve this using javascript.

Comment: it will be possible only if the iframe content is from same domain.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
//On load of iframe 'onLoadHandler' function will be called
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="my-frame" src='143/safety_starter/index_scorm.html' onload="onLoadHandler();"></iframe>
```

**JS**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function onLoadHandler() {
    var iframe = jQuery('#my-frame').contents();
    var _height = iframe.find('#cpDocument').height() + 'px';
    jQuery('#my-frame').css('height',_height);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: its not working and yeah iframe content is from same domain

Comment: Can you please add alert height and width inside function so we can comes to know that function is calling on load of iframe or not..

Comment: nothing is coming out, so function is not calling onload

Comment: i tried again no luck. Please help me out, i am sharing files link from google drive. [https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BywBz89KGUGfZnpBWTdfcHY5cFU&usp=sharing](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BywBz89KGUGfZnpBWTdfcHY5cFU&usp=sharing)

Comment: I have checked your index.html but there is no any div with class="cpMainContainer" in your index.html

Comment: "cpMainContainer" , "main_container" , etc all are coming from index_scorm.html file. If you inspect element of iframe it shows there.

Comment: @prem Please check my updaed answer. And update me whether it is working or not.

Comment: Please alert the width variable in function and check in console whether it throws any error?

Comment: i am getting an error; Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null

Comment: put console.log(innerDoc); right after var innerDoc = obj.contentDocument || obj.contentWindow.document; and check are you getting the div with id cpDocument in it?

Comment: hii, i am getting this: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BywBz89KGUGfbWNWWVhYYngydjg

Comment: This is correct. Really strange. If you are getting it then innerDoc.getElementById('cpDocument') should work. But not getting why not getting.

Comment: Can you able to use jquery function by including default jquery?

Comment: yeah, i am confused, can you elaborate

Comment: If you can include default jquery and use jquery functions then it might be work. Give id to your iframe "my-frame"
var iframe = jQuery('#my-frame').contents();
var width = iframe.find('cpDocument').width();
var height = iframe.find('cpDocument').height();

Comment: still no luck. i put codes like :                                                                                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var iframe = jQuery('#my-frame').contents(); 
var width = iframe.find('cpDocument').width(); 
var height = iframe.find('cpDocument').height();
</script>
<body>
<iframe src='safety_starter/index_scorm.html' id="my-frame"></iframe>
</body></html>

Comment: still no luck! :(

Comment: are you there? i am so tensed and stuck.

Comment: Sorry dude I have tried all for you but don't get any output.. the strange is that it all works here in my local machine but not your side..

Comment: hi, can you send me your local files

Comment: The code which I am sharing with you I am checking it in my local machine..

Comment: As its not working over here, i am getting output like this with scrollbars; https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BywBz89KGUGfaE5hdlV3eEhVQ1k